# SQS Lambda function returns "Task timed out after 10.01s"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, fastapi

I have a simple use case where I insert a message into a standard SQS queue and return the message back via api call.
I send a couple messages to the sqs queue which triggers the lambda function shown below:

```
import json
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print('start')
    
    resp = requests.get("http://fe35-103-210-33-254.ngrok.io/receive-message").json()
    
    print(resp)
    
    print('end')
    
    return {
        'status':200,
        'message':resp
    }
```

The function calls an api which basically recieves the messages and deletes them after returning it

```
@app.get('/receive-message')
def receive_message():
    client = boto3.resource('sqs')

    queue = client.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='transactions')

    messages = queue.receive_messages(QueueUrl=queue.url, WaitTimeSeconds=10, MaxNumberOfMessages=10, VisibilityTimeout=60)

    context = []

    for message in messages:

        context.append(message.body)
        queue.delete_messages(QueueUrl=queue.url, Entries=[{'Id':message.message_id,'ReceiptHandle':message.receipt_handle}])

    print(context)

    return ','.join(context)
```

Here is the output i am returning on the terminal

```
←[33mWARNING←[0m:  WatchGodReload detected file change in '['C:\\Work\\payments\\sqs_poc.py']'. Reloading...
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Started server process [←[36m46472←[0m]
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Waiting for application startup.
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Application startup complete.
['hello']
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
['pqr']
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
['Testing']
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
['pqr']
←[32mINFO←[0m:     13.127.17.123:0 - "←[1mGET /receive-message HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[32m200 OK←[0m
```

And here is the output from the lambda test execution

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "2021-10-06T08:12:36.466Z aff8f3ac-683d-40cc-b80e-92d18ec2c9f1 Task timed out after 10.01 seconds"
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: aff8f3ac-683d-40cc-b80e-92d18ec2c9f1 Version: $LATEST
start
END RequestId: aff8f3ac-683d-40cc-b80e-92d18ec2c9f1
REPORT RequestId: aff8f3ac-683d-40cc-b80e-92d18ec2c9f1  Duration: 10010.58 ms   Billed Duration: 10000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 19 MB  
2021-10-06T08:12:36.466Z aff8f3ac-683d-40cc-b80e-92d18ec2c9f1 Task timed out after 10.01 seconds
```

Also, is there a way where I can get the whole queue and stop the polling when the queue is empty?

Comment: Why not extend the timeout?

Comment: @Marcin I added a timeout of 20 seconds. Still same

Comment: I presume that setting the timeout to 20 seconds caused a timeout after 20 seconds? If so, it sounds like the Lambda function is unable to reach a network location and is timing-out while waiting for a response. For example, it might be unable to access the `ngrok.io` site. You can add some debugging `print()` statements to confirm that this is where it is hanging. If so, your function probably does not have access to the Internet. **Question:** Is your function connected to a VPC? If so, why? (Try disconnecting it and see if that helps!)